# Creating an entity-relationship diagram about an art fairs and galleries business environment

Tags: database-design, erd, database-diagrams

**Scenario description**

The charactheristics of the business domain under consideration are:

- Each and every art item has a unique identifying number, and also a name and asking price.
- Art galleries participate in multiple art fairs.
- Each time a gallery participates in an art fair, the database stores the date, the name of the art fair date the gallery participated, the name of the art fair, a count of how many items the gallery brought to the fair, and a count of how many items sold.
- For each art gallery, the date and name of of the art fair, together, identify a trip an art fair. However, art fairs involve many vendors selling art, so a date and fair name pairing cannot identify a fair visit unless the gallery identifier is included.

**The issue**

I am stuck on this problem so far in that I have just two entities, Art Galleries and Art Fair connected by a relationship....

> However, art fairs involve many vendors selling art, so a date and fair name pairing cannot identify a fair visit unless the gallery identifier is included.

I don't think vendors are part of the entity-relationship diagram. The statement is saying a date and fair name cannot identify a fair visit unless the gallery identifier is included.

My ERD just has a box with 'Art Galleries' connected to a diamond with 'participate' connected to a box with 'Art Fair'.

Comment: [Art Galleries]--------<Participate>----------------[Art Fair]

Comment: My ERD just has a box with 'Art Galleries' connected to a diamond with 'participate' connected to a box with 'Art Fair'.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/97245/755.  See comments there for additional feedback on the question.